# f-string: unmatched '(' in line with function call

Tags: python, quotes, function-call, quoting, f-string

I'm trying to use f-strings in python to substitute some variables into a string that I'm printing, and I'm getting a syntax error.
Here's my code:

```
print(f"{index+1}. {value[-1].replace("[Gmail]/", '')}")
```

I only started having the problem after I added the replace. I've checked plenty of times and I'm certain that I'm not missing a parenthesis. I know that there are plenty of other ways to accomplish this, some of which are probably better, but I'm curious why this doesn't work.

Comment: `"[Gmail]/"` is attempting to use double quotes inside of a `f""` that uses double quotes, which you can't do. Use single quotes for strings inside of f-strings (if you're using double quotes for the f-string).

Comment: You have an f-string `f"{index+1}. {value[-1].replace("`, and a regular string `", '')}"`. Does the error make sense now?

Comment: That makes sense thank you!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Your problem is double quotes inside double quotes.
For example,

- OK --> `f"hello ' this is good"`
- OK --> `f'hello " this is good'`
- ERROR --> `f"hello " this breaks"`
- ERROR --> `f'hello ' this breaks'`

This one should work correctly:

```
print(f"{index+1}. {value[-1].replace('[Gmail]/', '')}")
```

Out of scope but still I do not advise you to use `replace` inside `f-string`. I think that it would be better to move it to a temp variable.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue,change all the double  quote within the parenthesis to single quotes.It should work
eg from
print( f" Water :  {resources["water"] }  " )
to
print( f" Water :  {resources['water'] }  " )

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31393221)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this does not work

```
x = 'hellothere'
print(f"replace {x.replace("hello",'')}")
```

error

```
    print(f"replace {x.replace("hello",'')}")
                                ^
SyntaxError: f-string: unmatched '('
```

Try this instead

```
x = 'hellothere'
print(f"replace {x.replace('hello','')}")
```

single quotes `'hello'`
output is

```
replace there
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do some string formatting (which in my opinion improves readability) :

```
print("{0}. {1}".format(index+1, 
                        value[-1].replace("[Gmail]/", "")))
```